# Postgres - Merging grouped rows into one row for insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data from a query and the shape pretty much looks like this:

```
| Id | category | value |
|----|----------|-------|
| 1  | 'a'      |  2    |
| 1  | 'b'      |  5    |
| 2  | 'a'      |  3    |
| 2  | 'b'      |  4    |
```

I'm wanting to group that data and insert it into a table of the following structure

```
| Id | category_a_value | category_b_value|
|----|------------------|-----------------|
|  1 |       2          |          5      |
| 2  |       3          |          4      |
```

Is there a nice way to achieve this in Postgres? I couldn't figure out to group the data how I wanted so eventually I tried a `INSERT INTO` and `on conflict` approach selecting from the orginial query but this failed because you can't affect a row multiple times.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres uses `filter`:

```
select id,
       max(value) filter (where category = 'a') as category_a_value,
       max(value) filter (where category = 'b') as category_b_value
from t
group by id;
```

You can then use `insert . . . select` to insert the results into an existing table.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant. I wasn't expecting such a straight forward answer. Thanks a lot.